# count the frequency that a value occurs in the end of a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset

```
|category|
cat a
cat a
cat b
cat b
cat a
cat b
cat a
cat a
cat a
cat a
```

I'd like to be able to return the total **4** for `cat a` that occurs at the end of the dataframe
in other words if `cat b` happens then the count starts over once another `cat a` is found

Comment: if the last row in the dataframe would be b, is your wanted answer still 4?

Comment: Do you mean “how many last “cat a” there Is?

Comment: yes @adirabargil how many last "cat a" are found.

Comment: @Morinator if the last one is b then answer should be 0 we want to have "cat a" at the end and count only "cat a" that are back to back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['category'] = np.where(df['category'] == "cat b", df['category'],np.nan)
df['category'].bfill().isna().sum()
>>>4
```

Comment: With pleasure, that you too!